# Responding to Touch events with hammer

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

Currently I'm using `code-A` to create a color box and pass it's value to another function `colChg()`. This works perfect.

Now I need use this with [hammerJS](https://github.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started)

`Code-B` is a sample code I found from their documentation. But I'm not understanding how to replace `.on("click"` with `Hammer(element).on("tap"` so that my current code `Code-A` will respond to touch devices as well.

**Code-A**

```
$.each(["#ff6600", "#ff0000", "#00ff00"], function(i, color) {
  $('<input class="colBtn" type="button">')
    .css("background-color", color)
    .on("click",$.proxy(colChg, null, color))
    .appendTo("#colSw");
});
```

**Code-B**

```
var element = document.getElementById('test_el');
    var hammertime = Hammer(element).on("tap", function(event) {
    alert('hello!');
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### With the jQuery plugin

If you want a neat jQuery integration, I would advise to use [this plugin](https://github.com/EightMedia/jquery.hammer.js/). It is developed by the same developer as Hammer's, it has just been split so as to lightweight the core release. You will be then able to use the Hammer methods directly on a jQuery object.

```
$('body').on('tap', callback);
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aymericbeaumet/qfu5mra9/3/).

#### Without the jQuery plugin

Otherwise you would have to access the raw DOM element from the jQuery object (which is really just a wrapper).

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aymericbeaumet/k46jeotg/2/).

Comment: Thanks. I tried your first method. But the colour boxes `["#ff6600", "#ff0000", "#00ff00"]` doesn't show? It appears that there's some issue adding `.hammer(hammer_options)`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd method works. But As you've recommended I'd like to use your first method. But for some reason I can't get it to work. If I include `jquery-2.1.0.min.js` would it suffice? or do I have include some other file too? What is the file you are reffereing as "plug-in"

Comment: You need need to include **jQuery**, **Hammer** and finally **jQuery.hammer** (in last as it depends on the both previous libraries).